# Draw the paths of these numbers from t=0 to t=$2\pi$ in the complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

Draw the paths of these numbers from t=0 to t=$2\pi$ in the complex plane:
$$e^{it}$$
$$e^{(-1+i)t}=e^{-t}e^{it}$$
$$(-1)^t = e^{t\pi i}$$

I only know the first one: unit circle since I don't see r in this case (i.e., r=1). How to interpret the other two numbers?

Can anyone tell me where I can find the graphs of these three?

Answer (score 0):

$t$ is real.  In the second $e^{-t}$ is real and is the radius as $|e^{it}|=1$. Can you see the link between the third and the first?

Comment: sorry, can you explain more?

Comment: At $t$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi , e^{-t}$ goes from $e^0=1$ to $e^{-2\pi} \approx 0.00187$

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find the graphs of these three?